# Cannot find build files during oci8 installation on MAMP 3.5

Tags: php, macos, mamp, oci8

I tried to install `oci8` extension on `MAMP 3.5` with `php 7.0.0` on `Mac OS X El Capitan`. I found some tutorials about install extension but no one has reported this problem before. When I execute `phpize`, I get the below error message:

```
 "Cannot find build files at '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php/build'. Please check your PHP installation."
```

I obtain the same message with the below command

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/pecl install oci8.
```

Comment: I solved with a PHP downgrade to 5.6.10 version. I followed this instructions http://caseymorford.com/2014/04/17/installing-oci8-with-mamp-pro/ and all worked fine.